# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'U'

Tags: swift, generics

I am writing below function to swap two numbers without using third variable but while compiling the code I am facing below error.

> Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'U'

Code Snippet

```
func swap<T: Numeric,U: Numeric>( a:T, b:U) {
     var value1 = a
     var value2 = b
     value1 = value1 + value2
     value2 = value1 - value2
     value1 = value1 - value2         
     print(value1)
     print(value2)
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you may seek this: `func swap<T: Numeric>(a:T, b:T) { ... }` but there are much better solutions in Swift for swapping two values.

Comment: `Numeric` is a protocol. You can not initialize it.

Comment: `func swap<T>( _ a: inout T, _ b: inout T) {
    (a, b) = (b, a)
}`

Comment: I want to achieve it using generic

Comment: Is that comment in response to my suggestion? If so, that is generic. It works for any type T.

Comment: 1- read about parameters types 
2- read about generics more, 
for your case swapping 2 values regarding the type , we know they just have to be the same type 
so why are you declaring 2 generics with that confirms to the  same protocol !
@vacawama gave you the function already just read more about it to understand generics a bit more